# Laravel 5.6 failed convert Object to Array

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to convert object to array in laravel.

here is my codeline:

```
public function parentUnitDropdown()                                                                                                                                                                              
         {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
             $parents = Unit::all()                                                                                                                                                                                        
                 ->filter(function ($item) {                                                                                                                                                                               
                     $lowestLevel = Unit::max('level');                                                                                                                                                                    
                     return $item->level != $lowestLevel;                                                                                                                                                                  
                 })                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                 ->map(function ($item) {                                                                                                                                                                                  
                     return [                                                                                                                                                                                              
                         'label' => $item->unit_name . ' - ' . $item->unit_short,                                                                                                                                          
                         'level_name' => $item->level_name,                                                                                                                                                                
                         'value' => $item->id                                                                                                                                                                              
                    ];                                                                                                                                                                                                    
                });                                                                                                                                                                                                       

            return response()->json($parents->toArray(), 200);                                                                                                                                                            
        }
```

and here the response I get :

```
{
    "0": {
        "label": "Government and Institutional Banking - GI",
        "level_name": "directorate",
        "value": 1
    },
    "1": {
        "label": "Government and Institutional 1 - GI1",
        "level_name": "group",
        "value": 2
    }, ....
```

when I changed the value of $lowestLevel to integer (for example : $lowestLevel = 4)

here the response I get :

```
[
    {
        "label": "Government and Institutional Banking - GI",
        "level_name": "directorate",
        "value": 1
    },
    {
        "label": "Government and Institutional 1 - GI1",
        "level_name": "group",
        "value": 2
    }, ...
```

I think it supposed to be array whether input 4 or "Unit::max('level')", because, when I use gettype() both show integer.

Would you be able to help and explain to me what happened here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the [`values()`](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#method-values) method to reset the array keys before returning the underlying array:

```
return response()->json($parents->values()->all(), 200);
```

Comment: man, would you explain to me why can't just use toArray method ?

Comment: `toArray()` would work as well, but you would still need the `values()` method. The difference between `all()` and `toArray()` is that `all()` will return the underlying object directly and `toArray()` will map all values to arrays.